# Pre Authenticated Datasource using JDBC in Kubernetes/Docker Containers

Tags: java, docker, jakarta-ee, jdbc, kubernetes

During the migration from Java Enterprise web applications such as Tomcat or Weblogic to Kubernetes (or any container orchestration solution), this question raised that because there is no alternative out of the box to handle the connection pool and dynamic data source creation/connection pool feature in the Kubernetes for Java.

Because of this issue secrets should be injected to the containers through the volumes or environment variables which makes the credentials available to the application (developers) in plain text.

Any solution or work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If an application developer can access the production tomcat/weblogic, he can gather the credentials as well, so there is no difference with kubernetes.
If you want to prevent developers from getting data from production environments, appropriate access restrictions must be in place.

A kubernetes secret could be used to provide credentials, for more elaborate scenarios a special service like hashicorp vault could be used.

Comment: They don't have the necessary access to tomcat/WebLogic in our case. Specifically on prod. However, they can have access to logs for troubleshooting which is enough to disclose the credentials if they got passed environment variables.

Comment: A secret can be mapped to a file in the filesystem and is then not exposed as environment

Comment: my point is that if the code has access to credentials developer can print that out in the logs, compare to using the data source/connection pool/pre-authenticated connection.

Comment: You can use tomcat in your container as well, this is effectively the same situation as without kubernetes.

Comment: Thomas, could you please share more detail on this approach?

Comment: You can use whatever you like for your container image - if you want to use an appserver like tomcat to serve your application, you can absolutely do so and use a datasource that is available through jndi as usual.